# calculate how many days before a unix process time overflows

Tags: c, unix

I'm working through an example for Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment and the following questions was asked:

If the process time is stored as a 32bit signed integer, and the system counts 100 ticks per second, after how many days will the value overflow?

```
void proc_ovf()
{
        int sec = 60;
        int min = 60;
        int hour = 24;
        int tick = 100;
        int epoch_time = (((INT_MAX / (sec * tick)) / min) / hour);
        struct tm * timeinfo;
        time_t epoch_time_as_proc_t = epoch_time;
        timeinfo = localtime(&epoch_time_as_proc_t);
        printf("3] overflow date of proc: %s", asctime(timeinfo));
}
```

Is the following solution a reasonable calculation for how many days before overflow?

**(((INT_MAX / (sec * tick)) / min) / hour)**

This calculation yielded 248 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

248 days looks good.

But your code doesn't. Your variables have the wrong names. They should be:

```
int ticks_per_second = 100;
int seconds_per_minute = 60;
int minutes_per_hour = 60;
int hours_per_day = 24;

int ticks = INT_MAX;
int seconds = ticks / ticks_per_second;
int minutes = seconds / seconds_per_minute;
int hours = minutes / minutes_per_hour;
int days = hours / hours_per_day;

printf("overflow after %d days\n", days);
```

The above code takes care of mentioning the measurement units. Can you see how nicely the measurement units cancel out in each line of the second part of the code?